# SQL TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes

Tags: python, mysql

Running this piece of code returns a type error of 'can't concat tuple to bytes', but in my codes I don't see where the bytes are coming from, hence unsure how to fix my codes. Any pointers on which line of codes is in the form of bytes?

```
def array2python():

     mfcc = "US"
     number = 8 #could be any number from 0 to 9
     t = (number, mfcc)
     conn = pymysql.connect( host=hostname, port = port, user=username, passwd=password, db=database, charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor )
     cur = conn.cursor()
     query = ('INSERT INTO audioFiles VALUES (?,?)', t)
     cur.execute(query)
     conn.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
query = ('INSERT INTO audioFiles VALUES (?,?)', t)
```

You are *defining the `query` as a tuple* which then `execute()` fails to understand.

You mean to do:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO audioFiles VALUES (?,?)'
cur.execute(query, t)
```

And, I think you need to use [`%s` as a placeholder](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute):

```
query = 'INSERT INTO audioFiles VALUES (%s,%s)'
cur.execute(query, t)
```

Comment: I suspected that I need to do %s but would this invite SQL injections?

Comment: @jc76 if you use these `%s` placeholders to do string formatting - then, ys. But, in our case we are using them as query placeholders and passing parameters in a second argument to `execute()`. Thanks.